# Sp_OADestory is not clearing/destroying created object

Tags: sql, web-services

I am using sp_oacreate to call a webservice. The webservice just outputs a string queried from a database.
Here's the sequence:

- sp_oacreate -> creates instance of MSXML2.XMLHTTP
- sp_oamethod -> opens connection
- sp_oamethid -> send
- sp_oamethod -> get responseText
- sp_oadestory -> release memory of object created

I tried to change the data in the database to check if changes are reflected during webservice call, but the output is always the same from the first run. It seems that sp_oadestroy wasn't really able to free the memory or seems like it's using a cache. Memory issue?

To elaborate, here's a sample run and/our output:

- updated database: 1,2,3,4
- first run output: 1,2,3,4
- updated database: 1,2,3,4,5
- second run output: 1,2,3,4
- .... so on with same output

I know CLR is best for this but CLR is not available in SQL2000, so it's not an alternative. And let's say I really have to do this in SQL2000.
Hotfix or patches? Let's say, administrators won't allow or risk (no further questions on this :D)

Please shed some light over this issue. Thanks a lot!

Here's part of the code:

```
SET @url = 'http://url_showtext.php?val1=1&val2=2'
EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @object OUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @object, 'open', NULL,'get', @url, 'false'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @object, 'send'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OADestroy @object
select @ResponseText
```

And just a note by the way, please don't ask or ridicule much on why I'm using sp_oacreate and call this webservice thing via sql please. I've seen much of such and they are not helping to get to the point, really. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's unlikely that SQL Server caches the result of sp_OAMethod.  I'd add logs to the web service to see what is happening, or alternatively, inspect the HTTP traffic with Wireshark.

Comment: Thanks! To add up, the output only changes if the parameters (val1, val2) are changed. But when I try to use again the same parameter value, the output is the same the last time I run it even if the database is updated. For example: first run [val1=1,val2=2,output=hello], second run [val1=3,val2=4,output=world]... but if i use the parameter values from the first run again, the output is still "hello" even if I change the "hello" value in database to "star"... that's why I said it's like cached, though I'm not concluding. Would appreciate your assistance @Andomar.

Comment: Sounds like the web server is caching answers for requests with the same URL.  You can test that by adding an unused extra parameter, like `val2=2&randomval=128940`

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking about adding a parameter with random value passed on it just to get over this issue. So, do you think this is because of server caching and not some memory leak issues in sp_oacreate?

Comment: I think I got it. It's really being caused by caching in web server. I added "no-cache" statements in the webpage being called by sp_oamethod. Thanks a lot @Andomar. You gave me some hint on web caching. I just made sure that this is really caused by caching & not some memory leaks in sp_oamethod, so I tried adding "no-cache" in the web page. And it's working! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll have to answer my own question in case others stumble upon this issue:

Just add "no-cache" statement on the upper part of the webpage.
In my case, sp_oamethod just called a simple asp classic page.

So, just add in the asp page:

```
Response.Expires = 0
Response.Expiresabsolute = Now() - 1
Response.AddHeader "pragma","no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "cache-control","private"
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to make any changes to anything. The page that is retrieved is actually cached by Internet Explorer

So you just need to set the option "Every Time I visit the webpage" in Internet Explorer/Internet Options/Temporary Internet Files and History Settings/Check for newer versions of stored pages